# Get Closest match for a column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data Frame which contains different call types as below values

```
    CallType
0         IN
1        OUT
2       a_in
3       asms
4   INCOMING
5   OUTGOING
6  A2P_SMSIN
7        ain
8       aout
```

I want to map this in such a way the output would be

```
    CallType
0       IN
1       OUT
2       IN
3       SMS
4       IN
5       OUT
6       SMS
7       IN
8       OUT
```

I am trying to use difflib.closestmatch but it gives no result . Below is my code

```
CALL_TYPE=['IN','OUT','SMS','VOICE','SMT']

def test1():
    final_file_data = pd.DataFrame({
        'CallType': ['IN', 'OUT', 'a_in',
                         'asms', 'INCOMING', 'OUTGOING','A2P_SMSIN',
                         'ain', 'aout']})

    print(final_file_data)
    final_file_data['CallType'] = final_file_data['CallType'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, CALL_TYPE, n=1))
```

The output I get is below which as results only for IN and OUT

```
 CallType
0     [IN]
1    [OUT]
2       []
3       []
4       []
5       []
6       []
7       []
8       []
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with `get_close_matches` being `case-sensitive` and the `cutoff` for the score that is gotten for similarity. You can manipulate the `x` string to `upper()` and change the `cutoff` to be less stringent. This is what I did:

```
final_file_data['CallType'] = final_file_data['CallType'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x.upper(), CALL_TYPE, n=1, cutoff=0))
```

final_file_data is now:

```
  CallType
0     [IN]
1    [OUT]
2     [IN]
3    [SMS]
4     [IN]
5    [OUT]
6    [SMS]
7     [IN]
8    [OUT]
```

You can read more about the `get_close_matches` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) to read more about the `cutoff` argument.